# DNSMASQ Error in Syslog

Tags: network-manager, dns

I was browsing my syslog and I found this error:-

NetworkManager[984]:  [1407179609.489726] [nm-dns-dnsmasq.c:393] update(): dnsmasq not available on the bus, can't update servers.

NetworkManager[984]:  [1407179609.489790] [nm-dns-dnsmasq.c:395] update(): dnsmasq owner not found on bus: Could not get owner of name 'uk.org.thekelleys.dnsmasq': no such name

NetworkManager[984]:  DNS: plugin dnsmasq update failed

It does not seem to cause any problems to me but I wonder what it is and whether it needs any action.